# Accessing data set over WCF without serializing the entire thing?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, entity-framework

I'm very new at WCF (and .NET in general), so I apologize if this is common knowledge.

I'm designing a WCF solution (currently using Entity Framework to access the database).  I want to grab a (possibly very large) set of data from the database, and return it to the client, but I don't want to serialize the entire set of data over the wire all at once, due to performance concerns.

I'd like to operation to return some sort of object to the client that represents the resulting data and I'd like to deal with that data on the client, being able to navigate through it backwards and forwards and retrieve the actual data over the wire as needed.

I don't want to write a lot client code to individually find out what rows meet my search criteria, then make separate calls to get each record if I can help it.  I'm trying to keep the client as simple as possible.

Ideally,  I'd like to write the client code similar to something like the below pseudocode:

```
Reference1.Service1Client MyService = new Reference1.Service1Client("Service1");

DelayedDataSet<MyRecordType> MyResultSet = MyService.GetAllCustomers();

MyResultSet.First();

while (!MyResultSet.Eof)
{
    Console.Writeline(MyResultSet.CurrentRecord().CUSTFNAME + " " + MyResultSet.CurrentRecord().CUSTLNAME);
    Console.Writeline("Press Enter to see the next customer");
    Console.Readline();
    MyResultSet.Next();
}
```

Of course, DelayedDataSet is something I just made up, and I'm hoping something like it exists in .NET.

The call to MyService.GetAllCustomers() would return this DelayedDataSet object, with would not actually contain the actual records.  The actual data wouldn't come over the wire until CurrentRecord() is called.  Next() and Previous() would simply update a cursor on the server side to point to the appropriate record.  I don't want the client to have any direct visibility to the database or Entity Framework.

I'm guessing that the way I wrote the code probably won't work over WCF, and that the functions like CurrentRecord(), Next(), First(), etc. would have to be separate service contract operations.  I guess I'm just looking for a way to do this without having to write all my own code to cache the results on the server, somehow persist the data sets server side, write all the retrieval and navigation code in my service library, etc.  I'm hoping most of this is already done for me.

It seems like this would be a very commonly needed function.  So, does something like this exist?

-Joe

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not what WCF is designed to do.

In WCF, the very basic core architecture is that you have a client and a server, and nothing but (XML-)serialized data going between the two over the wire.

WCF is **not** a *remote-procedure call* method, or some sort of *remote object* mechanism - there is **no** connection between the client and the server except the serialized message that conforms to the service (and data) contracts defined between the two.

WCF is **not** designed to handle huge data volumes - it's designed to handle individual messages (`GetCustomerByID(42)` and such). Since WCF is from the ground up designed to be **interoperable** with other platforms (non - .NET, too - like Java, Ruby etc.) you should definitely **not** be using heavy-weight .NET specific types like `DataSet` anyway - use proper objects.

Also, since WCF ultimately serializes everything to XML and send it across a wire, all the data being passed must be expressible in XML schema - which excludes interfaces and/or generics.

From what I'm reading in your post, what you're looking for is more of a "in-proc" data access layer - not a service level. So if you want to keep going down this path, you should investigate the repository and unit-of-work patterns in conjunction with Entity Framework.

More info:

- [MSDN: What is Windows Communication Foundation?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)
- [WCF Essentials—A Developer's Primer](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/31674)
- [Picture of the very basic WCF architecture](http://assets.devx.com/articlefigs/16175.jpg) from that Primer - there's only a wire with a serialized message connecting client and server - nothing more; but serialization will **always** happen

Comment: Yes, I'm starting to understand that WCF is meant for small pieces of data at a time.  Though, it does seem that as newer version of the .NET/WCF come out, they do seem to be able to serialize more and more complex data types, which is what gave me that idea.  I still think WCF is the right solution, as it is useful for abstracting the database away from the client.  The issue is getting the smaller chunks of data as needed.  It just seems to me that there could/should be an easier way to do it, other than hand-writing all the code to do it.